# A nonzero unital division ring $D$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

A nonzero unital ring  $D$ in which every nonzero element is
invertible is called a division ring.

I think when the ring is divided, the following two are equivalent?Is it right?

> 1:  For all $a, b \in  D$ with $a \neq 0$, the equations $ax = b$ and $ya = b $ have
>   unique solutions in $D$.
>
> 2:  For all $a, b \in  D$ with $a \neq 0$, the equation $ax = b$  has a solution in $D$.

**Can the below statement  be obtained from The second case above?**

> 3:$D^{2} \neq 0$ and $D$ has no right ideals other than $0$ and $D$.

**Does the phrase 3 alone indicate a unital ring??**

Comment: What relationship and what second case? What is a neutral element? What is the last statement trying to say? What are $x$ and $y$?

Answer (score 0):

As I showed you [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2501894/29335), (2) implies there are only trivial right ideals.

Then [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2505026/29335) I showed you that as long as multiplication isn't zero ($D^2\neq \{0\}$) that having only trivial right ideals implies $D$ has an identity.

Then obviously there are no proper left ideals either, and $ya=b$ has a solution when $a$ is nonzero.

Finally, the solutions to $ax=b$ and $ya=b$ are unique since left and right multiplication by nonnegative elements is injective again [as previously mentioned to you here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2505026/29335). So (1) does indeed follow from (2) as long as you are still talking about $D^2\neq \{0\}$.

> I think when the ring is divided,

I don't know for sure what you mean, but I suspect you mean "the ring is divisible" like a divisible module, meaning $D=xD$ for any nonzero $D$, which is just a fancy way of saying $D$ is a division ring when $D^2\neq\{0\}$.

> Does the phrase 3 alone indicate a unital ring??

At first glance, perhaps no, but it is true, and you [already asked this and got the positive answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2505026/29335).

Comment: @jak If you continue to ask the same questions over and over and don't connect any dots between them, I think this may be the last answer I write for you. Good luck.