# Problem regarding an associative ring being a division ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, division-ring

I was trying to solve a problem in C. Musili's book "Introduction to Rings and Modules" and I got stuck while trying to solve the following problem:

> Let $R$ be a non-zero ring such that the equation $ax = b$ has a solution in $R$ for all $a, b \in R, a \neq 0$. Show that $R$ must have unity and it is a division ring.

What I tried are as follows:

- Before talking about invertibility we need the unity element $1$ and for a candidate we look at the equation $ax = a$ and obtain the solution, say $e$. Then show that $e$ is the required unity element.
- After this look at solutions for the equation $ax = 1$ and get invertibility for all nonzero elements, showing that $R$ is a division ring. Commutativity of the inverses follows from showing the left and right inverses of $a$, say $b$ and $c$ respectively are equal. $ba =1$ and $ac = 1$ and so $b = c$.

My problem is with the first half itself. I am presently stuck trying to show that $ea = a$ as well, and the uniqueness of $e$ irrespective of choice of $a$. I don't have a clue on how to proceed. Any hints at trying to solve this are welcome.

Comment: Not. $ax=a$ can have non-unity solutions in a general ring. So your first step is a bit tricky. If $x$ is not a unit, then you need to show that this would violate the property that $cx=d$ always has a solution when $c\neq 0.$

Comment: [Also relevant](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2508719/29335)

Comment: In the future please choose titles that are descriptive of the problem.  Titles of the format "problem about <subject area>" are, as a rule, useless.

Comment: The big step is to first show the ring has no zero-divisors. This can be done by solving $ax=a$ then $by=x,$ getting $aby=a,$ and thus $ab$ is non-zero if $a,b$ are non-zero.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Thanks for the hint

Comment: @rschwieb Understood. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews I see. I didn't realise that I needed to look into zero divisors. I was looking at if it were not an unity element and not beyond. Thanks again!